# Using Runtime exec() to pass a control character

Tags: java, terminal, exec, beep, control-characters

I'd like my java program to make a Windows machine beep when the program is run. Typing `^G` (Control-G) in the command prompt causes a beep sound.

Is there a way to use `Runtime`'s `exec()` to pass a control character to the command prompt?

e.g. `runtime.exec(CONTROL_G); // hmm`

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10771441/230513).

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064066/230513).

Comment: @nLee unfortuantely that answer doesn't solve my problem. Since exec() expects a string I can't simply send the number 7 :(

Comment: @CSStudent if all you want is a beep, see the question trashgod linked; otherwise, you could use the answer nLee linked - use a ProcessExecutor to run "cmd.exe", and write the command code to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what environment you are in, but on Windows using Cygwin, I use the following:

`String.valueOf((char) 27)` which is the escape character, followed by the control character